# How to read data from a .csv file to a multidimentional array using c language?

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, csv

In matlab we can do it using the code :

```
a= csvread('filename.csv');
```

But using C programming i used the following code but it doesnt works please help :

```
int main(){
int i,j,temp,m1=0,n=0;
//CSV file reading
int ch;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("filename.csv","r"); // read mode
if( fp == NULL )
{
  perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
  {printf("%d",ch);}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}

mat[i][j] = ch;
int m1 = i;
int n = j;
}
```

Please help !

Comment: A couple of questions. Will the values in the csv always be integers? Do you know the number of values in the file before you read the file? For example, will it always be say 5 rows of 4 columns?

Comment: Define "doesnt works". (At first glance, you seem to have difficulties implementing simple loop logic.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this hasn't been extensively tested but it should read a csv file that has integer values and store them in an (n x m) matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    //CSV file reading
    int rowMaxIndex,columnMaxIndex;
    int **mat;
    int *matc;
    int i,j,idx;

    char part[1024];
    char *token;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("filename.csv","r"); // read mode
    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // count loop
    rowMaxIndex = 0;
    columnMaxIndex = 0;
    while(fgets(part,1024,fp) != NULL){
        token = NULL;

        while((token = strtok((token == NULL)?part:NULL,",")) != NULL){
            if(rowMaxIndex == 0){ // only want to increment column count on first loop
                columnMaxIndex++;
            }
            for(idx = 0;idx<strlen(token);idx++){
                if(token[idx] == '\n'){ // this assumes there will be a \n (LF) at the end of the line
                    rowMaxIndex++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // allocate the matrix
    matc = malloc(rowMaxIndex*columnMaxIndex*sizeof(int));
    mat = malloc(rowMaxIndex*sizeof(int*));

    for(idx = 0;idx<rowMaxIndex;idx++){
        mat[idx] = matc+idx*columnMaxIndex;
    }

    // rewind the file to the beginning
    rewind(fp);

    // read loop
    i = j = 0;
    while(fgets(part,1024,fp) != NULL){
        token = NULL;
        while((token = strtok((token == NULL)?part:NULL,",")) != NULL){
            mat[i][j] = atoi(token);
            j = (j+1)%columnMaxIndex;
        }
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```